# construction of this sentence here?

Tags: grammar

> この本がバカ売れすれば、遊んで暮らすだけの金が手に入るのに。

Can anyone breakdown this part 遊んで暮らすだけの金 and explain the sentence construction ?

Comment: Highly related: https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/57298/is-%e8%b6%b3%e3%82%8a%e3%82%8b%e3%81%a0%e3%81%91-with-a-negative-verb-idiomatic

Answer (score 2):

> XしてYする

Y-ing by X-ing.

遊んで暮らす means "To live while just doing nothing but playing"

> XするだけのY

Enough amount of Y to X.

So,

> 遊んで暮らすだけの金

means

> Enough amount of money to live by playing.